# How to check if the values of a column exist in a column of another table in SQL Presto or Hive?

Tags: sql, dataframe, hive, hiveql, presto

So, let's say that I have two tables. Table1 and Table2 and I want to see if the values of the column ID of Table1, also exist in column ID of Table2.

The query that I tried was this one:

```
SELECT ID 
FROM Table1 
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Table2)
```

but although I see that they have some values that are the same, the result is 0.
So, how can I see which IDs of Table1, also belong to the ID column of Table2?

Comment: if `ID` is string or timestamp, please use LTRIM(RTRIM(ID)) or TRUNC(timestamp) on both sides and the compare.

Answer (score 0):

Try with join:

```
  SELECT ID FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID=Table2.ID
```

Comment: if dosent work add commen